# Logout user with systemd

Tags: systemd, logout

I start my window manager with systemd service units (following [this tutorial](http://pbrisbin.com/posts/systemd-user)).
After I log in at `tty1` the following gets executed in `.zlogin` (I'm using ZSH as a login shell):

```
if [[ -z "$DISPLAY" && $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
  nohup systemd --user > ~/.xlog 2>&1 &
  disown %2
  logout
fi
```

Systemd starts a X server, a window manager, ... through service units.

The problem starts when I want to logout.
*Should I simply execute `kill $MANAGERPID` to kill the systemd daemon ?*
It seems much cleaner to do a `loginctl terminate-session $XDG_SESSION_ID` but this command requires further privileges.

**Here's the question: What is the preferred way to log out with the setup described above ?**

Answer (score 10):

This is what I use to log out from using xmonad (after using `wmctrl` to close all open windows):

```
session=`loginctl session-status | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
loginctl terminate-session $session
```

I'm not sure why you need further privileges for `loginctl terminate-session` - this works for me without any such need.

Also note that there are different ways to obtain the session ID. In this example I simply take it directly from `loginctl` itself. There's also `$XDG_SESSION_ID` (as you wrote) and `/proc/self/sessionid`.

Comment: `loginctl session-status | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`...