# How to change user home directory when in use by /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user

Tags: systemd, usermod

After copying all contents of a user home directory I'm trying to change the home directory to the new location. But systemd prevents me from doing this.

```
# sudo usermod -d /data/home/user/ user
usermod: user user is currently used by process 10050
# sudo ps -fp  10050
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user       10050       1  0 Nov23 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

How can I achieve this ?

I'd like to avoid stopping services or rebooting the server just to move a home directory

The user is not logged on, I checked using `sudo who`

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa)
```

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321096/70524 help?

Comment: Did not work in Linux Mint. I can see the sessions with "sudo loginctl list-sessions" but when I try to termintate the session, it does nothing - also no error msg.

Answer (score 3):

You can forcefully logout the user via

```
sudo pkill -KILL -u {username}
```

After that your user should be free, you can check with

```
sudo loginctl list-sessions
```

and the usermod command should work.

Comment: this helped me get past the `user is currently used` error.

Answer (score 1):

did you try using -m option with -d ?

```
sudo usermod user -m -d /data/home/user/
```

Comment: The data already has been “moved” (really, copied here).

Comment: same issue, as long as the systemd process is present